# How should I initialize the contents of a large matrix in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to initialize a matrix (using the Eigen library) to have a nonzero value when I create it. **Is there a nice way to do this without a for loop?**

For example, if I wanted to initialize the whole matrix to 1.0, I would like to do something like:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd mat(i,j) = 1.0;
```

or

```
Eigen::MatrixXd mat(i,j);
mat += 1.0;
```

(I am used to this type of thing in MATLAB, and it would make Eigen even nicer to use than it already is. I suspect there is a built-in method somewhere that does this, that I have not found.)

A sub-question to this question would be how to set a block of matrix elements to a set value, something ilke:

```
mat.block(i,j,k,l) = 1.0;
```

Comment: I found an answer, but it would still be nice to have a syntax like I proposed... :)

Comment: Close to what you want: multiply the scalar by `Eigen::MatrixXd::Ones(rows,cols)`, like: `Eigen::MatrixXd mat(3,3) = 1.5 * Eigen::MatrixXd::Ones(3,3)` It's not quite like MATLAB, but close

Comment: The syntax you tried works with `Eigen::Array` but not with linear algebra matrices because in this case a scalar value should rather be assimilated as the identity matrix times this scalar value.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As so often happens I found the answer in the docs within thirty seconds of posting the question. I was looking for the [`Constant` function](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#abb7652b9ae2c6ee26be9db276613c4f6):

```
Eigen::MatrixXd mat = Eigen::MatrixXd::Constant(i, j, 1.0);

mat.block(i,j,k,l) = Eigen::MatrixXd::Constant(k, l 1.0);
```

Comment: There are also other "init" functions, like `Eigen::Matrix::Zero()` or `Eigen::Matrix::Ones()` http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html

Comment: As well as the `setConstant(val)`, `setOnes()`, `setZero()`, `fill(val)` variants which are more compact to write with less redundancy in your cases.

Comment: Be cautious of the parameters for block and Eigen::MatrixXd::Constant. ( i, j ) is the starting position of the block, and ( k, l ) is the size of the block. So, I think in the second example the ( i, j ) pair on the right hand side should be ( k,l ).

Comment: Are the variables `i` and `j` indices or the number of rows and columns?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 It's the number of rows and columns. I just corrected my post based on jmcarter9t's comment.

Answer (score 11):

`Eigen::MatrixXd::Ones()`, `Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero()` and `Eigen::MatrixXd::Random()` can all give you what you want, creating the Matrix in a dynamic way.